# Inertia detect api request 303 in nuxt js and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, inertiajs

I have a challenge in the code below how can be able to detect response in my index component approve method from my lender controller so that I could be able to set the loading to false again if the API request is successful which is the status of API request is 303 and the onSuccess in inertia it will detect status 200. What are your insights to solve my problem?

Here is my index component with approve method:

```
approve(marketLocation) {
  this.loading = true;
  this.$inertia.patch(
    this.$route("admin.marketLocation.approve", { id: marketLocation.id }),
    {
      preserveState: true,
      onSuccess: (response) => {
        console.log("Success:", response);
          this.loading = false;
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        console.log("Error:", error);
        this.loading = false;
      },
    }
  );
},
```

Here is my index component with approve method:

```
   public function approve($id)
    {
        $lenderMarketLocation = $this->fetchLenderMarketLocation($id);
    
        if ($this->canBeApproved($lenderMarketLocation)) {
            $this->approveMarketLocation($lenderMarketLocation);
            $this->sendApprovalNotification($lenderMarketLocation);
            $this->saveLenderMarketLocation($lenderMarketLocation);
        }
    
        $message = 'Market location approved.';

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', $message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try onFinish event

> onFinish: visit => {},

it is called when call is completed. here are the reference [docs](https://inertiajs.com/manual-visits).

Comment: I tried to implement your suggestion but is not working.